# Проблема с муsql

Tags: php, mysql, post

Ошибка при отправке пост запроса

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/u249644105/public_html/getUser.php on line 12
>
> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/u249644105/public_html/getUser.php on line 14

Сам код

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    //Getting values 
            $imei = $_POST['imei'];
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE imei='$imei'";
require_once('dbConnect.php');
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
$array = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $array['username'];
}
```

При отправке имея в POST запросе найти его в базе данных и отправить ответ в виде привязанного к нему имени username

Comment: Откройте мануал http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php и посмотрите как процедурный стиль функции пишется.

Answer (score 0):

Обратимся к документации [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php), где указано:

```
mixed mysqli_query(mysqli $link, string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ])
```

То есть, в первую очередь указывается ссылка на переменную с подключением, а затем запрос.

Не могу точно сказать, что у вас подключаемом файле, так что возьму из примера:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
```

Тогда надо будет написать:

```
$db_result = mysqli_query($link, $sql); // обратите внимание на $link!
```

Собственно, второй варнинг вам про то же и говорит: мне надо правильные данные, а не null (или что там возвращает в таком случае?).

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

Comment: Всеравно: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in /home/u249644105/public_html/getUser.php on line 19

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, то что сейчас получилось в http://pastebin.com/ например.